# 10G SFP+ Synology NAS to SuperMicro X10

Tags: 10gbethernet

I'm trying to directly connect my Synology NAS to a SuperMicro X10 built PC:

- Synology DS1618+
- 10Gtek MCX312B-XCCT PCIe NIC
- Using 10Gtek SFP-H10GB-CU1.5M DAC cable
- Supermicro X10SDV-8C-TLN4F+ mobo w/ Intel X552 10G SPF+ ports

The issue that I'm running into is that when either the Synology or the Supermicro server are connected to a 10G SFP+ switch, I get link activity on both of them using the passive DAC. However when I connect them to each other, the links fail to negotiate and I get no link activity with both sides showing as disconnected.

Does anyone have any ideas here? Could there be an incompatibility between the 10Gtek NIC and the Intel X552? Or am I doing something incorrect here?

Thanks,
-Ryan

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be the DAC cables' fault - maybe. It's surely not listed in the HCL :-)

You might want to borrow one that is contained here:

https://www.synology.com/en-global/compatibility?search_by=category&category=sfp_module_da_cables&filter_type=Direct%20Attach%20Cables&p=1